# Jekyll Liquid sub-navigation not properly selecting

Tags: jekyll, liquid, github-pages

I'm building a static website on [gh-pages](/questions/tagged/gh-pages) using [jekyll](/questions/tagged/jekyll) [liquid](/questions/tagged/liquid). I'm properly generating a simple, two-level navigation from a data file. My problem is that I am stuck trying to do two things:

1. Apply a "selected" class to the current page link item.
2. Apply an "open" class to the parent list item when a sublink menu is present.

Here's the format I'm using in my `_data/nav.yml` file

```
- title: Top Level Nav Item
  url: level-1/
  sublinks:
    - title: Child Nav Item 1
    url: child-1/
    - title: Child Nav Item 2
    url: child-2/
```

Here's how I'm building my navigation:

```
{% assign current_page = page.url | remove: 'index.html' %}
<ul class="-nav">
{% for nav in include.nav %}
    {% assign current = null %}
    {% if nav.url == current_page %}
        {% assign current = ' _selected' %}
    {% endif %}
    {% if nav.url contains current_page %}
        {% assign open = ' _open' %}
    {% endif %}
    <li class="-item{{ current }}{{ open }}">
        <a href="{{ site.url }}{{ nav.url }}">{{ nav.title }}</a>
        {% if nav.sublinks and current_page contains nav.url %}
            {% include navigation.html nav=nav.sublinks%}
        {% endif %}
    </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Again this builds my navigation correctly, but it doesn't apply either the selected or open class.

Here's what I'm would like it to look like in the end:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not sure this matters for the output, but you have inconsistent quotations around values. Also, what happens when you remove the `{% assign current = null %}` statement?

Comment: @JoelGlovier Nothing happens when I remove `{% assign current = null %}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally got this working. I solved it by adding an item to the front matter of my page called `permalink` where I specified the desired page permalink.

```
---
layout: default
title: Example
permalink: url/example/
---
```

I use this permalink to check against the current `page.url` to add the desired `_selected` class on the `<li>` element.

I made one modification to my example data file, adding in the parent url_part into the child's url. I'm not sure why, but I had trouble printing the entire URL correctly otherwise.

```
- title: Top Level Nav Item
  url: level-1/
  sublinks:
    - title: Child Nav Item 1
    url: level-1/child-1/
    - title: Child Nav Item 2
    url: level-1/child-2/
```

Lastly for my `navigation.html` include, here's how I'm creating my main menu, rendering sub-menus if they exist and should be shown, and properly selecting the active link:

```
{% assign current_page = page.url | remove: 'index.html' %}
<ul class="-nav">
{% for nav in include.nav %}
    {% assign current = null %}
    {% if nav.url == page.permalink %}
        {% assign current = ' _selected' %}
    {% endif %}
    <li class="-item{{ current }}">
        <a href="/{{ nav.url }}">{{ nav.title }}</a>
        {% if nav.sublinks and current_page contains nav.url %}
            {% include navigation.html nav=nav.sublinks%}
        {% endif %}
    </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

The big difference between this and the snippet I originally posted is I dropped the `{{ open }}` stuff for now. One problem at a time. The other thing is that I'm checking to see if `nav.url` equals `page.permalink`. Before I was checking against `page.url` and this always failed for me.

It's probably not the prettiest, but I finally got a [jekyll](/questions/tagged/jekyll) [liquid](/questions/tagged/liquid) menu to generate (semi-)dynamically and properly select the active link.